# Botium botpress connector got 403 Forbidden response

Tags: botpress, botium-box

I am trying to run simple test with botium CLI. For that purpose I wanted to use botpress chatbot,
so I followed instructions from "https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-botpress" and installed botium CLI, botium connector botpress and configured botium.json file.

But after executing "botium-cli hello" to test my configuration I am getting 403/Forbidden response:

`403/Forbidden [31m Connectivity check FAILED`

This is how my botium.json file looks like:

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "Botpress Chatbot Tests",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "botpress",
      "BOTPRESS_SERVER_URL": "https://mediafiles.botpress.cloud",
      "BOTPRESS_BOTID": "ee.............12afaff",
      "BOTPRESS_TOKEN": "bp_............URySnP"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Here is complete output with --verbose option:

```
+     & "node$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/botium-cli/bin/botium-cli.js ...

+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (2024-02-29T09:1...e ./botium.json:String) \[\], RemoteException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

2024-02-29T09:19:08.294Z botium-cli-hello command options: {
\_: \[ 'hello' \],
verbose: true,
v: true,
convos: \[ '.' \],
C: \[ '.' \],
config: './botium.json',
c: './botium.json',
messageText: 'hello',
'message-text': 'hello',
'$0': 'C:\\Users\\......\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\botium-cli\\bin\\botium-cli.js'
}
2024-02-29T09:19:08.296Z botium-core-BotDriver Loaded Botium configuration files C:\\depot\\botium\\botium.json
2024-02-29T09:19:08.448Z botium-core-BotDriver Build - Botium Core Version: 1.11.15
2024-02-29T09:19:08.448Z botium-core-BotDriver Build - Capabilites: {
PROJECTNAME: 'Botpress Chatbot Tests',
TESTSESSIONNAME: 'Botium Test Session',
TESTCASENAME: 'Botium Test Case',
TEMPDIR: 'botiumwork',
CLEANUPTEMPDIR: true,
WAITFORBOTTIMEOUT: 10000,
SIMULATE_WRITING_SPEED: false,
SIMPLEREST_PING_RETRIES: 6,
SIMPLEREST_PING_TIMEOUT: 10000,
SIMPLEREST_PING_VERB: 'GET',
SIMPLEREST_PING_UPDATE_CONTEXT: true,
SIMPLEREST_PING_PROCESS_RESPONSE: false,
SIMPLEREST_INIT_PROCESS_RESPONSE: false,
SIMPLEREST_STOP_RETRIES: 6,
SIMPLEREST_STOP_TIMEOUT: 10000,
SIMPLEREST_STOP_VERB: 'GET',
SIMPLEREST_START_RETRIES: 6,
SIMPLEREST_START_TIMEOUT: 10000,
SIMPLEREST_START_UPDATE_CONTEXT: true,
SIMPLEREST_START_PROCESS_RESPONSE: true,
SIMPLEREST_START_VERB: 'GET',
SIMPLEREST_POLL_VERB: 'GET',
SIMPLEREST_POLL_INTERVAL: 1000,
SIMPLEREST_POLL_UPDATE_CONTEXT: true,
SIMPLEREST_METHOD: 'GET',
SIMPLEREST_IGNORE_EMPTY: true,
SIMPLEREST_TIMEOUT: 10000,
SIMPLEREST_EXTRA_OPTIONS: {},
SIMPLEREST_STRICT_SSL: true,
SIMPLEREST_INBOUND_UPDATE_CONTEXT: true,
SIMPLEREST_CONTEXT_MERGE_OR_REPLACE: 'MERGE',
SCRIPTING_TXT_EOL: '\\n',
SCRIPTING_XLSX_EOL_WRITE: '\\r\\n',
SCRIPTING_XLSX_HASHEADERS: true,
SCRIPTING_CSV_SKIP_HEADER: true,
SCRIPTING_CSV_QUOTE: '"',
SCRIPTING_CSV_ESCAPE: '"',
SCRIPTING_NORMALIZE_TEXT: true,
SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY: false,
SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MULTIPLE_ASSERT_ERRORS: false,
SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE: 'wildcardIgnoreCase',
SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_MODE: 'all',
SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_RANDOM_COUNT: 1,
SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_NAMING_MODE: 'justLineTag',
SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_NAMING_UTTERANCE_MAX: '16',
SCRIPTING_MEMORYEXPANSION_KEEP_ORIG: false,
SCRIPTING_FORCE_BOT_CONSUMED: false,
ASSERTERS: \[\],
LOGIC_HOOKS: \[\],
USER_INPUTS: \[\],
SECURITY_ALLOW_UNSAFE: true,
CONTAINERMODE: 'botpress',
BOTPRESS_SERVER_URL: 'https://mediafiles.botpress.cloud',
BOTPRESS_BOTID: 'eeda.............afaff',
BOTPRESS_TOKEN: 'bp_pa................RySnP',
CONFIG: './botium.json'
}
2024-02-29T09:19:08.448Z botium-core-BotDriver Build - Sources : { LOCALPATH: '.', GITPATH: 'git', GITBRANCH: 'master', GITDIR: '.' }
2024-02-29T09:19:08.448Z botium-core-BotDriver Build - Envs : { IS_BOTIUM_CONTAINER: true }
2024-02-29T09:19:08.639Z botium-connector-PluginConnectorContainer-helper Botium plugin botium-connector-botpress loaded. Plugin version is 0.0.4
2024-02-29T09:19:08.639Z botium-connector-botpress Validate called
2024-02-29T09:19:08.640Z botium-cli-hello Conversation container built, now starting
2024-02-29T09:19:08.640Z botium-connector-botpress Start called
2024-02-29T09:19:08.787Z botium-connector-botpress success on url check https://mediafiles.botpress.cloud/api/v1/bots/eeda...............2afaff/converse/d182ba28-a68a-4698-a8eb-aa6185797e2c
2024-02-29T09:19:08.787Z botium-cli-hello Conversation container started.
2024-02-29T09:19:08.788Z botium-connector-botpress UserSays called { sender: 'me', messageText: 'hello' }
2024-02-29T09:19:08.788Z botium-connector-botpress constructed requestOptions {
"uri": "https://mediafiles.botpress.cloud/api/v1/bots/eeda..............aff/converse/d182ba28-a68a-4698-a8eb-aa6185797e2c?include=nlu,state",
"method": "POST",
"json": true,
"body": {
"type": "text",
"text": "hello"
}
}
2024-02-29T09:19:08.808Z botium-connector-botpress got error response: 403/Forbidden
got error response: 403/Forbidden
\[31m Connectivity check FAILED
```